# Changing Background Colour with a While Loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, background-color, tkinter-label

I am trying to configure a label in my window with the result of an iteration that produces the range of hexadecimal colour codes from #000000 to #FFFFFF so that the label’s background colour fades through all the possible colors between #000000 and #FFFFFF with a fraction of a second interval but it doesn’t seem to complete the loop before stating at #000000 again.

I have used the the print method to display the colour code being deployed with every loop and it doesn’t seem to be restarting as the display does.

```
from time import *
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *


def changing_color():
    global color
    while True:
        for i in range(0, 2**24):
            r = format(i, "02x")
            for j in range(0, 255):
                g = format(j, "02x")
                for k in range(0, 255):
                    b = format(k, "02x")
                    color = "#"+r+g+b
                    print(color)
                    date_label.config(bg=color)
                    day_label.config(bg=color)
                    window.update()
                    sleep(0.01)


def update_frame1():

    day_string = strftime("%A")
    day_label.config(text=day_string)

    date_string = strftime("%d, %B %Y")
    date_label.config(text=date_string)

    frame1.after(1000, update_frame1)

def update_frame2():

    time_string = strftime("%I:%M:%S:%p")
    time_label.config(text=time_string)

    frame2.after(1000, update_frame2)


window = Tk()
window.title("RO'Clock")

color = ""


frame1 = Frame(window)
frame1.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

frame2 = Frame(window)
frame2.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

date_label = Label(frame1, font=("Ink Free", 20))
date_label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

day_label = Label(frame1, font=("Ink Free", 15))
day_label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

time_label = Label(frame2, font=("Consolas", 30), fg="#00FF00", bg="black")
time_label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")


update_frame2()

update_frame1()

changing_color()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you have: `for i in range(0, 2**24):`, but the inner loops have: `range(0, 255)`? Did you mean: `range(256)` for all three loops?

Comment: using `sleep` in your `changing_color` is blocking the mainloop as well. Use `after()` as you did with the clock instead of the endless loop!

Comment: Yes. I want every possible colour combination.

Comment: How long do you think it should take to go through every color?

Comment: Quite some time I imagine but I simply want to create smooth kind of glide through all the colors while the program is running.

Comment: I have removed the sleep() and ended the whole loop with window.after(1000, changing_color) and I can now see other colors but the transition is too fast. Any idea how I can get a smother transition?

Comment: you also should think of your looping logic since the cycling through all values leads to permanent changes in luminance meaning that it looks like it is flickering. you might want to only select color combinations of somewhat equal brightnes

Comment: Jan_b please tell me what to do to use the code you cleaned up for me. It executes but doesn’t run program.

Comment: You just need to add two lines to the end of that answer: `r = RoClock(); r.mainloop()`

Comment: Did this and now the window opens without any display :(

Comment: I'll edit this into the answer. It works well for me.

Comment: Okay thanks. My knowledge of OOP is very poor. I realized this the moment I didn’t know what to do with the class he created. 
Sir, please mentor me I have to get this right this year. Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned your imports and translated it into an OOP approach for better readability and also to get rid of global variables. Your endless loop is now a recursive function using `after` and incrementing the color values each cycle.

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label
from time import strftime


class RoClock(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("RO'Clock")
        self.color = ""

        self.frame1 = Frame(self)
        self.frame1.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.frame2 = Frame(self)
        self.frame2.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.date_label = Label(self.frame1, font=("Ink Free", 20))
        self.date_label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.day_label = Label(self.frame1, font=("Ink Free", 15))
        self.day_label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.time_label = Label(self.frame2, font=("Consolas", 30), fg="#00FF00", bg="black")
        self.time_label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.update_frame2()

        self.update_frame1()

        self.changing_color(0, 0, 0)  # passing starting values

    def changing_color(self, k, j, i):  # new recursive function using after instead of endless while loop
        if k == 256:
            k = 0
            j += 1
        if j == 256:
            j = 0
            i += 1
        if i == 256:
            i = 0

        r = format(i, "02x")
        g = format(j, "02x")
        b = format(k, "02x")
        color = "#"+r+g+b
        print(color)
        self.date_label.config(bg=color)
        self.day_label.config(bg=color)
        self.after(1, self.changing_color, k+1, j, i)

    def update_frame1(self):
        day_string = strftime("%A")
        self.day_label.config(text=day_string)

        date_string = strftime("%d, %B %Y")
        self.date_label.config(text=date_string)

        self.frame1.after(1000, self.update_frame1)

    def update_frame2(self):
        time_string = strftime("%I:%M:%S:%p")
        self.time_label.config(text=time_string)

        self.frame2.after(1000, self.update_frame2)

r = RoClock()
r.mainloop()
```

While this is working it is not pretty! To get rid of the flickering you have to rethink how you calculate your colors to get colors of equal brightness!